# NSArrayController returns null

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsarraycontroller

I have an NSArrayController bound to CoreData in my application. It is also bound to a TableView that displays the data. Two buttons are bound to the ArrayController that add and remove lines. All of this is working as expected. I can add, edit, save, and remove CoreData Entries.

There is a section of my app that is to accept drag and drop operations from files (working). It takes the data from the files, looks for various information, and is to insert this information into the Core Data database via the NSArray Controller.

I have added the class handling the parsing/adding of the file to the database as an object in IB. I created an IBOutlet for the array controller in the class, and bound the controller to the class' referencing outlet.

If I add a button to the interface to directly call the method that adds a custom record to the database, everything works. If the method is called via the drag and drop operation, nothing works, even logging a simple [arrayController className] returns null (though returns NSArrayController as expected when the method is called from the button click).

The only difference I can see is that when accessed through the button click, the method is called directly, while the other way passes through my drag and drop class before loading the parsing class, but I'm completely stuck on how to remedy this situation. I'll be happy to provide code,  just not sure which code you'll need.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

==================

UPDATE
turns out I was connecting the IBOutlet to a class (a subclass of a view) object in IB instead of to the view itself handling the drops. Connecting these up made things work. Well, not work, I have other issues to iron out now, but the Array controller is now instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved from comment to answer: The array controller you are trying to add stuff is not instantiated. I assume you are not referring to your original NSArrayControllerinstance but maybe a new created one? Probably a problem of communication between your class instances.

Comment: Yeah, Not instantiated was what I was figuring. I'm just not sure why.  As I said above, the instantiation works when I access a method in the class directly through the UI, so the binding to the attribute to the NSArrayController Is correct. However, the drag drop operation passes through a different class before being shot over to the one handling the insertion. Hrm. I just got an idea, I'll go give it a try.

Comment: This is probably the closest answer to what I ended up finding. I have a view that is subclassed to add the drag and drop functionality. The subclass itself was added as an object in IB and all my bindings were to that class instead of to the view itself. Once I bound to the view itself, the array controller was suddenly no longer null.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging this should be straightforward ... using the debugger. Set a few breakpoints (one at each action the button(s) call, and one at each point where your class instances are meant to talk to each other (your importer and your main controller)). Run, test, step through the code when the debugger breaks at each breakpoint.

My guess: An outlet is not hooked up (is nil) in IB or is not yet reconnected at runtime (see `-awakeFromNib` and make sure you're not trying to touch an outlet or action that hasn't been fully reconnected from the nib at runtime by the time you're trying to use it).

Answer (score -1):

Something’s not hooked up right, BUT you don’t want to do it this way anyways. There’s no advantage to inserting via an NSArrayController. Just create new objects with `NSEntityDescription`s:

```
+ (id)insertNewObjectForEntityForName:(NSString *)entityName inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
```

And you’re done. If your `NSArrayController` is hooked up correctly it’ll auto-fetch the new objects at the end of the event so the user will see them “immediately.”

Comment: "There’s no advantage to inserting via an NSArrayController."  -- Sure there is. If you use the add/insert methods and `selectsInsertedObjects` is `YES`, the inserted/added objects will be automatically selected after insertion (a very common use case). Otherwise, you have to wait for the change to show up in your current context or force-update the array controller, find it, and select it yourself.

Comment: Ok, fine, there’s that advantage, but the flip side is if you insert via your ArrayController you have to look up the objects you just inserted manually if you want to modify them, which you most often do. So I meant, it’ll be net less code my way. Also, OP didn’t say (s)he wanted the items selected.